# Handling Django Static Files in production

Tags: django, python-3.x, production-environment

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files/')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I've deployed my project on the digital ocean but after setting "DEBUG = False", static files (CSS, js, image) are not loading. I also tried giving STATICFILES_DIRS but still, nothing changed.

Comment: Can you include the web server's site configuration as well? Did you run `./manage.py collectstatic` inside the virtual env?

Comment: What is the value of `BASE_DIR`?

Comment: That is because Django is not supposed to serve static files on prod. Configure Nginx for this.

Comment: @Dauros yeah I did run "./manage.py collectstatic" but still it's only loading when DEBUG=True

Comment: @Vinay ok, then can you describe how did you deployed the Django app to DO? Which web server did you use, what is the site configuration?

Comment: @IvanStarostin yeah Nginx did it for me.
Thanks man